# How do I prevent flash from automatically showing (i.e. make it "click to play") in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

There is a built-in way to have FlashBlock functionality in Chrome, but it isn't obvious in the Options menu. Anyone remember what the steps are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114662

> Use the Content Settings dialog to
>   manage the following settings:
>   cookies, images, JavaScript, plug-ins,
>   pop-ups, location sharing, and
>   notifications. Follow these steps:
>
> Click the wrench icon  on the browser
>   toolbar. Mac users: If you don't see
>   the wrench icon, go to the menu bar at
>   the top of your screen and click
>   Chrome. Select Options (Preferences on
>   a Mac). Click the Under the Hood tab.
>   Click Content settings in the
>   "Privacy" section. Click the tabs to
>   manage different settings: ... Plug-ins
>   are used by websites to enable certain
>   types of web content (such as Flash or
>   Windows Media files) that browsers
>   can't inherently process. They're
>   allowed by default.

Apparently the Chrome developers [changed things around](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/11/chromes-click-to-play-plug-in-settings-moved-to-aboutflags/) so that the option has to be enabled from the `about:flags` page (type that into your browser and hit enter - bottom of the screen is "Click-to-play"). Then you might still need to do the procedure above.

Comment: It won't even touch JavaScript (since it is not an external plugin). Every other plugin (such as Java & co.) will behave exactly like the Flash plugin.

Comment: That's the ticket. All the way at the bottom of `about:flags` on Chrome 8.0.552.210 beta (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Click the "customize" icon at top right. Choose `tools` then `extensions` enter "flashblock" into the search field.

Answer (score 0):

Under the settings tab, go to under the hood, click on content settings and click on the plugins tab, there are three choices including a click to play button

Comment: The only options I see there are `Run automatically` and `Block all`.

(8.0.552.210 beta)